# Create a database from AWS S3 bucket that contains a csv file

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Hi I'm trying to create a new database using data from an s3 bucket as my source, its in a CSV format

Please see screen shot below

Answer (score 1):

Use **AWS Datapipeline** . It is designed for that exactly .

[amazon-data-pipeline](/questions/tagged/amazon-data-pipeline)